# SQL - Transpose query data with additional rows added in

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have come once more to seek your guidance.
I am not actually sure how possible this is, but I can only hope.

I have an already heavily joined and aggregated query which pulls out results as shown in the attached picture.

[image: Query as it currently shows]

As mentioned, this is an already heavily editing query with multiple joins and aggregates to take half hour data and sum it hourly.

I am wondering if it is at all possible to now transpose the data so that there are 24 seperate hourly entries for each date?

So instead of having one single line for 2014-01-01 with each hourly reading in a seperate column, is it at all possible to change it so there are just two columns. One for date/time and one with the hourly total.

So it would look more like:

[image]

and then continue down for each hour of each day.

I am using SQL Server 2014 if that helps.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The answer is almost certainly yes, and probably would use a numbers/tally table with an outer join; a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would make things clearer.

Comment: You could unpivot it using an `APPLY`. Please add your query to the question, there is probably something even simpler

Comment: Please [edit] this question to type the text from the image so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your time columns are named `time0`, `time1`, ..., `time23` you could write

```
SELECT DateAdd(HOUR, 0, date) as DateTime, time0 as total from table
UNION
SELECT DateAdd(HOUR, 1, date) as DateTime, time1 as total from table
UNION
...
SELECT DateAdd(HOUR, 23, date) as DateTime, time23 as total from table
```

Comment: To all who have responded thank you. For some reason notification emails were going into my junk so only just seen your replies now! 

Thank you for the advice on the formatting without images I will keep this in mind for the future. 

Henning, your answer worked perfectly thank you. I also reaslised a simple indexmatch in Excel would do the trick as well, but it is always great to learn new methods, particularly in SQL.